# Flask-Login. Where do I store users for the user_loader function to find them?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

According to Flask's documentation:

> user_loader(callback):
>   This sets the callback for reloading a user from the session. The function you  set should take a user ID (a unicode) and return a user object, or None if the user does not exist.

From where is this funciton supposed to load the User object? User data is stored in the session, but that isn't a user object, its just a JSON blob of info about the user. Without storing user objects in some global dictionary or something, I have no idea how this function is supposed to take a user_id and return the associate user *except* by creating a new user with that id, and mapping all previous data to it.

I should mention that I am not using a database (and even if I were the same problem would present itself--databases can't store user objects, they just store data about users) because I am using authentication credentials stored in an LDAP server.

Here is some code:

```
    class User(object):

        def __init__(self, user_id, password, active=True, authenticated=False, anonymous=False):
            self.user_id = user_id.upper()
            self.password = password
            self.active = active
            self.authenticated = authenticated
            self.anonymous = anonymous

        def is_active(self):
            return self.active

        def is_anonymous(self):
            return self.anonymous

        def is_active(self):
            return self.active

        def is_authenticated(self):
            return self.authenticated

        def get_id(self):
            return self.user_id
```

and my view function:

```
    @mod.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        form = LoginForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

            user_id = form.user_id.data
            password = form.password.data

            user = User(user_id=user_id, password=password)


            conn = get_ldap_connection(user.user_id, user.password)

            if conn:
                login_user(user)
                user.authenticated = True

                next = request.args.get('next')
                if next:
                    print("next: ", next)
                    return flask.abort(400)

            return redirect('/mmt')
        return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

Every example I can find of an implementation for the user_loader function makes use of SQLALchemy.session.add(user) but as I mentioned I'm not storing my users in a database... they already exist in a different database.

Comment: The short answer is in memory, just like session data.  Flask's built in session class does something very similar.

Comment: What's the long answer? flask.session only seems to be able to store JSON data, not Python objects

Answer (score 4):

You don't store the user in the session, you store a unique value to identify the user.  Then you use that id to load the user.  In the case of a database, you would store the primary key of the user, then query by that key.  You can do the exact same thing with LDAP: store some unique value in the session, then load from LDAP based on that value.

The user just has to be an object that inherits from `flask_login.UserMixin` (or implements everything it does, which your example code doesn't, the `_is` attributes should be properties).  So you'd load the record from LDAP and pass that data to your `User` class to create a user.

In your login view, create a user object based on the record you load from LDAP, and call `login_user(user)` with it.  Flask-Login calls the user object's `get_id` method to store a unique value in the login cookie.  On subsequent requests, Flask-Login calls `user_loader` to load the user based on the value in the cookie; this function would perform an LDAP query and create a user, similar to the login view.  The user object you return from `user_loader` is stored in `current_user` for the duration of the request.